# Prestashop 1.5.4.1 Turkish character does not show correctly

Tags: prestashop

My prestashop has a problem with Turkish characters. I tried different things like changing font in classes/pdf PDFGenerato.php from helvetica to freeserif. I tried different character sets But couldn't find a right combinnation of them :( 
Someone in a forum suggested that font sets should be changed so I backuped \tools\fpdf\fonts and installed that fonts.zip package but nothing changed :( 
What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with arabic characters. I even reported the bug, but did not get any reply from there

http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFV-6253?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

PS is using tcpdf behind the scene for generating PDF invoices. The tcpdf coming with PS has some missing fonts, which you need to place there. **[Download tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/)** . In the download you will see a fonts folder. Compare that folder with the PS tools/tcpdf/fonts folder and you will see the missing fonts. Copy and paste that folder to tools/tcpdf .

Next change the fonts at your classes accordingly and i hope it will work for you. For me it fixed the issue, but did the currency text ( ر يال ) was not displaying correctly.

Also checkout the example files coming with the tcpdf download.

Thank you